# How do I drop SVG files onto an VSE timeline?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, svg

I have an SVG logo that I would like to drop onto a VSE timeline (organisation logo). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use another application to convert it to a bitmap image of the resolution you want to use in the video and then use it in blender.

Blender doesn't know how to read svg files, there is an Import SVG addon which will read an svg file and create curve objects in the 3D view but blender doesn't know how to treat them as images.